# Can NodeJs be used on the web just like php

Tags: node.js, web

Guys i'm new in Nodejs,

please can it be used on the web like php?

Comment: Did you read NodeJS documentation ? The about page says it clearly https://nodejs.org/en/about/

Comment: On the web - yes. Like php - no.

Comment: that means if i want to use it on the web i must use it with php?

Comment: Take time to read the documentation posted by @MatthieuLemoine. It has all the answer your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you decide what type of situation you have.
If you want to make shopping site, social network etc which use large data processing , then you go for node.js (for example linkedin is made in node.js ).

But if your website does not require much data processing in server side you can go for php.

Nodejs is little difficult to use but once you use it perfectly your website will run smooth.

Both are good languages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily use nodejs as a server side language.
Nodejs is faster than php. You can use nodejs to speedup your loading speed of your website.

Because nodejs heavily use callbacks.

Comment: I am good at php but the truth is that i don't know which is better